# I installed a python package on Windows using pip. Why can't I call it from the command line?

Tags: command-line, python, powershell

In Powershell I installed boto-rsync using pip:

```
PS> pip install boto-rsync
```

That installed boto-rsync in C:\python27\Scripts as 'boto-rsync' as expected. I have C:\python27\Scripts  in the path (pip.exe is there) but I can't invoke my new package from the command line, e.g:

```
PS> boto-rsync *from* *to*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run Python scripts in PowerShell. (You can in Unix shells). You have to do this:

```
python.exe path/to/some/script.py
```

That assumes python.exe is in your path. Otherwise you have to do something like this:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe path/to/some/script.py
```

Comment: Not quite right. You *can* run Python scripts in PowerShell directly, given that they have the correct extension and are in the search path. If they have the `.py` extension, you can either call it with `script.py`, or add `.py` to the `PATHEXT` envvar and call it without the extension, just `script`. *However*, `boto-rsync` does not have an extension at all - as far as Windows is concerned, it is a file containing arbitrary data and cannot be directly executed (Windows does not use the shebang).

Comment: @Bob, thanks, I did not know that. I think Dizzley's best option here would be to write a little PowerShell wrapper script that calls python.exe with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: Yes, that is likely the best idea. You should edit that into your answer. (Actually, a batch script would work just as well in this case, potentially better if you don't want to deal with PS execution policies... also, `.ps1` isn't in `PATHEXT` by default either.)